# Aggregate dataframe with NA in R

Tags: r, aggregate

*This was probably asked before, but i haven't found an answer to my problem.*

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
  id        col1  col2  col3  col4
1 111111    car   <NA>  NA    NA
2 111111    <NA>  bike  NA    NA
3 111111    <NA>  <NA>  2     NA
4 111111    <NA>  <NA>  NA    3

5 222222    plane <NA>  NA    NA
6 222222    <NA>  train NA    NA
7 222222    <NA>  <NA>  4     NA
8 222222    <NA>  <NA>  NA    5
```

How can I aggregate by `id` to get a dataframe similar to this one:

```
  id        col1  col2  col3  col4
1 111111    car   bike  2     3
2 222222    plane train 4     5
```

Comment: What if any column has multiple values for a `id` ?

Comment: Every column (within a specific `id`) can only have  one value.

Comment: @Khashaa it looks like all these approaches only work with numeric values. My dataframe on the other hand contains also strings, so `sum` won't probably work.